# REST framework puts the data but doesn't change them

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using rest framework to serialize my data, and I created a serializer successfully like following, but when I fill in the form and send it, it sends but my data don't change without even one error! and the blank fields remain still blank without change! What should I do?

[image]

## Serializer.py:

```
class UserProfileSignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    verification_code = serializers.ReadOnlyField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['id', 'gender', 'birthday', 'country', 'city', 'street_address', 'state', 'about', 'social_links',
                  'location', 'avatar', 'verification_code']


class UserSignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = UserProfileSignUpSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'user_profile')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_profile_data = validated_data.pop('user_profile')
        for attr, value in user_profile_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance.user_profile, attr, value)
        # UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance, **user_profile_data)
        instance.save()
        instance.user_profile.save()
        return instance
```

## Views.py:

```
class UserSignupDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSignUpSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        signup = User.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        return signup
```

## Permission.py:

This file specifies the level of permission as just owner only can edit the objects.

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.


        return obj.username == request.user.username
```

I have a model here, Profile, in which exists several object and a one to one filed corresponded to auth.User; and a subclass named Userprofile.

## Model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=get_image_path)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    persian_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    social_links = models.TextField(blank=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    location = GeopositionField()


# User Profile
class UserProfile(Profile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile')
    gender = models.CharField(choices=sex, max_length=1)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,11}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: "
                                                                   "'9123456789'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    call_no = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=False, default='9123456789')
    verification_code = models.CharField(default=generator(4), max_length=5, blank=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked tried using 'POST'.  Also make sure the form is not cached with the old data, I have had this issue myself.

Comment: I have to use 'PUT' because I want to update the information, but how can I do `Also make sure the form is not cached with the old data`?

Comment: If you means to in the browser, I click on F5 several times, but no changes!

Comment: One simple way is to get the form and add some random query string number so you know the get is returning a new value.  so if it is `GET user/userid=12345`  change it to `GET user/userid=12345&rnd=23048290`

Answer (score 0):

I changed my serializer.py to the following and it works OK:

```
class UserSignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = UserProfileSignUpSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'user_profile')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_profile_data = validated_data.pop('user_profile')

        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)

        instance.save()
        try:
            UserProfile.objects.get(user=instance)
            for attr, value in user_profile_data.items():
                setattr(instance.user_profile, attr, value)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance, **user_profile_data)
        instance.user_profile.save()
        return instance
```